# Simple camera code causes Nexus4 with Android V 5.01 to reboot

Tags: java, android, camera

This issue takes me a long time, searching through Net does not help.
I wrote a simple camera application that processes camera previews only, the code is attached below.
Running this code on Nexus4 (V 5.01) causes the device to reboot after a random time ranges from 1m to 30m.
I cannot say this reboot is due to a bug in the camera itself or in the running android version because "Camera HDR Studio" and "Barcode Scanner" apps run without problem.

Below is the code, i removed all unneeded checking code and camera releasing in order to simplify it.

XML:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <SurfaceView
      android:id="@+id/camerasurfaceview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Java code:-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public final class MyActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
       getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_credit_reader);

       SurfaceView SV = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerasurfaceview);
       SurfaceHolder mHolder = SV.getHolder();
       mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){}
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){}

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) 
    {
       try 
       {
           Camera m_camera ;
           m_camera = Camera.open() ;
           m_camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
           m_camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
           m_camera.startPreview();
       }
       catch (IOException e) 
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
   {
       // any processing for "byte[] data".
       double rr = 0 ;
       for(int y = 0 ; y < data.length ; y++)
       {
           rr += Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt((double)(data[y])));
           rr = Math.sin(rr);
           if(data[y] > 128)
               data[y] = (byte)Math.min(255.0, rr) ;
       }
   }
}
```

Manifist:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="test.example.camera"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="15"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_glass"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity
                android:name="test.example.camera.MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="orientation" 
                android:screenOrientation="landscape">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

And below is logcat

```
    01-20 10:30:15.983: D/OpenGLRenderer(4177): Render dirty regions requested: true
    01-20 10:30:15.990: D/Atlas(4177): Validating map...
    01-20 10:30:16.017: I/Adreno-EGL(4177): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
    01-20 10:30:16.018: I/OpenGLRenderer(4177): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    01-20 10:30:16.041: D/OpenGLRenderer(4177): Enabling debug mode 0
    01-20 10:30:16.084: W/AudioFlinger(191): acquireAudioSessionId() unknown client 4177 for session 20
    01-20 10:30:16.152: W/AudioFlinger(191): acquireAudioSessionId() unknown client 4177 for session 21
    01-20 10:30:16.189: I/Icing(1466): Indexing 708E85BDBFB1F209A370FF7D45917D504857502F from com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
    01-20 10:30:16.194: I/CameraClient(191): Opening camera 0
    01-20 10:30:16.261: E/qcom_sensors_hal(549): hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11 
    01-20 10:30:16.277: I/Icing(1466): Indexing done 708E85BDBFB1F209A370FF7D45917D504857502F
    01-20 10:30:16.283: E/mm-camera(203): sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx111_preview.so: 30
    01-20 10:30:16.384: W/linker(203): libmmcamera_faceproc.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
    01-20 10:30:16.396: E/mm-camera(203): vfe_ops_init: E
    01-20 10:30:16.420: E/mm-camera(203): vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
    01-20 10:30:16.421: E/mm-camera(203): vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
    01-20 10:30:16.426: E/mm-camera(203): mctl_init_stats_proc_info: snap_max_line_cnt =30096
    01-20 10:30:16.454: W/linker(191): libmorpho_noise_reduction.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
    01-20 10:30:16.461: E/QCameraHWI(191): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::setPreviewWindow(preview_stream_ops_t*): mPreviewWindow = 0x0xb8237b48, mStreamDisplay = 0x0xb81edf78
    01-20 10:30:16.461: D/QCameraHWI(191): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview():  start preview now
    01-20 10:30:16.461: I/QCameraHWI(191): android::status_t android::QCameraHardwareInterface::startPreview2():Setting ZSL mode
    01-20 10:30:16.466: E/mm-camera(203): config_proc_CAMERA_SET_INFORM_STARTPREVIEW
    01-20 10:30:16.469: E/mm-camera(203): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 1 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 810081 cid = 0
    01-20 10:30:16.507: E/mm-camera(203): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 3 as : width = 640, height 480, format = 1 inst_handle = 830083 cid = 0
    01-20 10:30:16.508: E/mm-camera(203): config_update_stream_info Storing stream parameters for video inst 4 as : width = 512, height 384, format = 1 inst_handle = 840084 cid = 0
    01-20 10:30:16.526: E/mm-camera(203): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Ports Used 3, Op mode 1
    01-20 10:30:16.526: E/mm-camera(203): config_decide_vfe_outputs Current mode 0 Full size streaming : Disabled
    01-20 10:30:16.527: E/mm-camera(203): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Primary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 1, Path: 1
    01-20 10:30:16.527: E/mm-camera(203): config_decide_vfe_outputs: Secondary: 640x480, extra_pad: 0x0, Fmt: 1, Type: 3, Path: 4
    01-20 10:30:16.530: E/mm-camera(203): config_update_inst_handles Updated the inst handles as 810081, 830083, 0, 0 
    01-20 10:30:16.665: E/mm-camera(203): sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx111_zsl.so: 26
    01-20 10:30:16.769: E/mm-camera(203): camif_client_set_params: camif has associated with obj mask 0x1
    01-20 10:30:16.769: E/mm-camera(203): config_v2_CAMERA_START_common CAMIF_PARAMS_ADD_OBJ_ID failed -1 
    01-20 10:30:16.782: E/mm-camera(203): vfe_operation_config: format 3
    01-20 10:30:16.782: E/mm-camera(203): vfe_operation_config:vfe_op_mode=5
    01-20 10:30:16.782: E/mm-camera(203): Invalid ASD Set Params Type
    01-20 10:30:16.782: E/mm-camera(203): vfe_set_bestshot: Bestshot mode not changed
    01-20 10:30:16.856: I/Choreographer(4177): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-20 10:30:16.880: E/mm-libcamera2(191): PROFILE HAL: First preview frame received: 1421742616.880144392
    01-20 10:30:16.888: E/QCameraHWI_Preview(191): processPreviewFrameWithDisplay: buffer to be enqueued is not locked
    01-20 10:30:16.948: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(993): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
    01-20 10:30:16.960: I/ActivityManager(549): Displayed bhtfactor.creditreader/.CreditReaderActivity: +1s268ms
    01-20 10:30:16.992: I/WindowManager(549): Screen frozen for +1s168ms due to Window{f8d7d98 u0 Starting bhtfactor.creditreader}
    01-20 10:30:19.134: I/art(549): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13496(649KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(637KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 20MB/31MB, paused 1.220ms total 93.880ms
    01-20 10:30:19.212: D/TaskPersister(549): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=1889_task.xml
    01-20 10:30:19.213: D/TaskPersister(549): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=1889_task_thumbnail.png
    01-20 10:30:25.005: V/ConfigFetchTask(1466): ConfigFetchTask getDeviceDataVersionInfo(): ABFEt1VL9vtrn_Q2kmWmuZxbSbSGw5Us2DjlF2hd_SzSN39NNSD12yIpWdeUqv6SJg5NkeMV2WI3vZvbvs04Y0RFz5CBKQACq1dTLx8j9StD0zUZXpcUPnG58d_f8fEEdGoLjWsJYrX2M41Can8c8pcprfwP07h1IffwaozVdYJJBRKqTV4KDV9TffHcLrFCO1U7QHEVPEPsHeb_QaAtz1o49YmRUKfWRyOWaAv0NR_FnA13lJqR3KqUEOtNs-5HwY-Pj0nhQWmewalD8g63KPEjuq1qEDny6THyv-QZAgkhTjgpF26Ud6c
    01-20 10:30:25.010: I/GoogleHttpClient(1466): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
    01-20 10:30:25.690: I/ConfigFetchService(1466): fetch service done; releasing wakelock
    01-20 10:30:25.692: I/ConfigFetchService(1466): stopping self
    01-20 10:30:25.699: I/ConfigService(1251): onDestroy
    01-20 10:30:34.381: D/Finsky(2199): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
    : E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: Please post the `adb logcat` logs.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar problem after Nexuses (4 and 10 atleast) updated to Android L. It's looks like firmware bug and unsolvable (Nexus 10 updated and fixed this but Nexus 4 still rebooting and camera stops responding). You can try builtin camera app - it has same problems.

Comment: For sure there is a bug with these devices, and this is discussed in many threads, but, what i am saying is that there is some work around that other apps like barcode scanner are using to hide this bug.

Comment: "Camera HDR Studio" is another app that does not reboot.

Comment: In nexus 4 every camera crashes if  you set color effects to emboss and sketch.